# Prove inequality for $a,b>0$

Tags: inequality

Prove the following inequality using Cauchy-Schwartz:
$$ 8(a^4+b^4)\ge(a+b)^4$$
I'm looking for HINTS.

Comment: BTW, that holds for all reals, not just positives.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$(1+1)(a^2+b^2)\geqslant (a+b)^2$$

Now repeat...